# Is there a way to randomly reorder/scramble a dataset held within a smart contract?

Tags: random, smartcontracts, chainlink

For example, let's say a smart contract has a bunch of addresses added into an array variable over a certain duration of time (many blocks).  I assume they are indexed into an array in the order in which they are written to the contract.  At the end of that duration, is there a way to scramble the indexes in which they are held?  Assume a verified random number (Chainlink's VRF) is used.

Comment: Why do you want to rearrange the array? Working with an array of more than several hundred elements in Ethereum is extremely expensive.

Comment: Trying to do a lottery/raffle where each ticket is weighted and there are multiple winners - so we can't use a simple random number call to pick a winner.  Was going to have to resort to doing this off chain, but if we can scramble the addresses, I think there is a way to do it all on-chain.

Comment: How about this idea (notice that this solution is O(n) which may be expensive and for long enough arrays tx will revert)? [Get multiple](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-multiple-random-numbers) random values [within the range](https://docs.chain.link/docs/chainlink-vrf-best-practices/#getting-multiple-random-numbers) and then iterate through your array and swap each element with element located in array at given random index like this `(addresses[i], addresses[random]) = (addresses[random], addresses[i]);`